# Partial order over morphism "types"

Tags: category-theory

We know there are "types" of morphisms: epi, mono etc.
In the category of sets, function is the top level morphism type.  In Set, every morhpism is a function.  Furthermore, every regular epi is also an epi and is also a function.  This suggests there is a partial order over all the types of morphisms.  Can someone give a reference with an exhastive list or diagram with all the types and the partial ordering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for, since your question is rather broad. But here's my attempt at classifying some common types of morphisms into a partial order, with $a>b$ representing the statement "$a$ is a stronger property than $b$":

[image]

This poset also has the agreeable property of being a *lattice*. That is, every pair of properties has a unique least upper bound and greatest lower bound, and further, in this poset, the LUB of two properties is given by their logical conjunction. For instance, the LUB of "mono" and "epi" is "mono and epi", and the LUB of "mono" and "split epi" is "isomorphism" (it is a theorem that every split epimorphism which is also a monomorphism must be an isomorphism).

Comment: This looks pretty good!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remark 7.76 in "Abstract and Conrete Categories. The Joy of Cats" by Adámek, Herrlich and Strecker shows an overview of different types of epi-/monomorphisms.

[image: Overview of Epi-/Monomorphisms]